# Encontrar elemento html no css

Tags: html, css

Eu preciso encontrar um elemento especifico do que está no meu código em html só que no css, exemplificando:

Da pra fazer tipo:

```
meuElemento [type=input]{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Só que a duvida está em como eu encontro um elemento como `id="textoUm"` do meu html por ID, não da pra simplesmente pegar e fazer  `[id=textoUm]`.

Como eu consigo fazer isso? Já procurei diversos sites da internet e não consegui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando o `attr` do css ficaria assim: (repare na construção do attr **[id="textoUm"]**)

```css
[id="textoUm"] {
 border: 2px solid red;
}

input { 
 border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textoUm" value="com ID">
<input type="text" value="sem id">
```

**OBS:** Mas se vc vai colocar o css usando o **ID** não tem por que usar o `attr[]` crie direto a classe `#textoUm {seu css}`

Quando vc coloca o estilo no **ID** tem que que começar o nome por `#textoUm {}` e quando cria um estilo para por na **classe** tem que começar o nome por `.textoUm {}`

Link da documentação da Mozilla sobre o css attr https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/attr está em PT e vai te ajudar vale a leitura

Comment: Valeu, era isso mesmo, mas acho que eu não estava acertando a sintaxe, tipo eu estava tentando colocar em um `p` ai estava assim `p [id=textoUm]{` não da pra fazer esse tipo de seleção?

Comment: Da sim! Mas o certo seria assim  `p[id="textoUm"]` com o P sem espaço do [ e com o valor do ID entre aspas id="textoUm"

Comment: Pow, valeu ai pela ajuda era isso mesmo que eu queria.

Comment: @Groot dmr tmj!

Answer (score 3):

Quando você quer utilizar com id ou class é mais simples

Exemplo com id:

```
#textoUm{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Exemplo com class:

```
.textoUm{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Ou se quiser algo como, um input com a class 'textUm' por exemplo, você pode fazer assim:

```
input.textoUm{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Ou com algum id:

```
input#textoUm{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Um pequeno exemplo:

```css
.texto{
  color: #f00;
}
#texto{
  color: #00f;
}
input.texto{
  color: #0f0;
}
input#texto{
  color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="teste" class="texto" />
<input type="text" value="teste" id="texto" />
<div class="texto">teste</div>
<div id="texto">teste</div>
```

Comment: Sim, mas não tem como fazer do jeito que eu coloquei la?

Comment: Nosso amigo hugocsl, postou uma resposta da forma que você deseja

Comment: Vlw a consideração jovem!